# According to the dropdown value, change the label name and value of an attribute in yii2 activeform

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, yii2, active-form

My active form :

dropdown

```
<?php
if($model->userType!="VENDOR" && $model->userType!="COMPANY"){
    echo $form->field($model, 'fixedOrPercentagevendor')->dropDownList([0=>'Percentage',1=>'Amount']);

}
?>
```

I need to get it done with onchange,

when I choose `Percentage`, it should show

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'vendorcommision')->label('Vendor Fee (%)')->textInput(['type' => 'number','value'=>'20', 'id'=>'percentage']); ?>
```

when I choose `Amount`, it should show

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'vendorcommision')->label('Vendor Fee (LKR)')->textInput(['type' => 'number','value'=>'1000','id'=>'amount']); }?>
```

Please Note that both dropdown options render the same attribute `vendorcommision` in the model and only the label names and values are different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Kartik's DepDrop extension](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop)

Comment: use dropdown instead of text input if you are trying to display only one input at a time based on choice, kartik dep dropdown can help you out as @gmc said

Comment: can't use the extension because my values should be **editable** or **changeable**, those are percentage and amount.   :(

Comment: the labels you want to show on choice are they initially hidden? what are the `id`'s of the 2 labels?

Comment: `'percentage'` and `'amount'` are the 2 id's. Initially can be hidden or only `'percentage'` id can be shown. @MuhammadOmerAslam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my issue.

```
<?php
if($model->userType!="ADMIN" && $model->userType!="HOST"){
    echo $form->field($model, 'fixedOrPercentagevendor')->dropDownList([0=>'Amount',1=>'Percentage'],
            [
                'onchange'=>'if($(this).val() == 1){
                    $("#percentage").val("20");
                    $("#ftype").html("Vendor Fee (%)");
                    }
                    else{
                    $("#percentage").val("1000");
                    $("#ftype").html("Vendor Fee (LKR)");}'
            ]);

    echo $form->field($model, 'vendorcommision',['template'=>"{label}\n<div>{input}</div>\n{hint}\n{error}",'labelOptions'=>['label'=>'Vendor Fee','id'=>'ftype']])
            ->textInput(['type' => 'number','id' => 'percentage']);
}
?>
```